# Can DBMS_ERRLOG be used in SQL*Loader functionality to catch the error while inserting tables?

Tags: oracle, toad, sql-loader, oracle19c

I am trying to get the Oracle Validation errors during the SQLLOADER in a table. Right now, the errors are generated in log file, I am trying to get that errors in a table. I have tried DBMS_ERRLOG but it works for INSERT statement but not with SQLLoader. Is there any way to use DBMS_ERRLOG to capture the error messages from SQL*LOADER?

Comment: Do you want to log just one specific file, or do you want to log everything? I can't find any SQLLOADER option in the manual for enabling DML logging. But if you only have a single file type, perhaps you could find out what SQL is generated in `GV$SQL`, intercept the SQL with DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE or SQL translation framework, and then force the statement to log, as described [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532032900346556030).